# Lighting chart : Mouse left click event is not working

Tags: lighting, lineseries

I am using Lighting chart line series and trying to create mouse left click but getting error.

chartSerie.onMouseClick((series, event) => {
});

Above code is working on on pointer , not working on line series. I need to create mouse click event on Line.

If anyone have any idea about mouse event on line series in Lighting chart . Please help